# Use PolicyKit to give my application access to restricted files

Tags: c#, linux, ubuntu, permissions, mono

I'm writing an [application](http://robinj.be/unity-2d-config-util/) for Ubuntu, which allows you to customize the Unity 2D desktop environment.
Some settings, I can change using Dconf, which is user-specific. So if one user changes a setting, it only applies for that user.
For other settings, however, I need to edit text files which are located in `/usr/share/unity-2d/`, to which a normal user can't write. To solve this problem, I thought it was a good idea to have users run the application as root, which makes sure they have access to `/usr/share/unity-2d/`. Only, when the application is running as root, and one of the Dconf settings is changed, it gets changed in the root user's Dconf, so the changes don't apply to the actual user.

I need to find a solution to this problem, and my first realistic idea was to use PolicyKit. I need to make sure that my application runs as the current user (so not always as root), but that it *does* have access to `/usr/share/unity-2d/` and the files inside it. I'm writing the application in C#, using the Mono framework. I don't really have any experience with PolicyKit, and to be honest this is my first attempt in making a serious Linux application.

My idea was PolicyKit, but if one of you has another (realistic) way to achieve this, that fine with me as well. If it comes down to using PolicyKit, I'd like to have a bit more information on how to do this, and what everything does, please. I know I can probably just run my application using `pkexec`, but I was actually thinking more among the lines of a button in my application to unlock the features which need access to that directory, which *at that moment* asks for a password to get writing access to the files in the folder. In this way, people who don't have special permissions on the system the application is running on, can still customize some basic settings.

Comment: I'm not familiar with the workings of Unity, but are you sure you want to be changing files under /usr/share/unity-2d? Typical Ubuntu packages are not supposed to write to /usr during normal operation (it's meant to be possible to mount /usr read-only when not installing/removing packages). And if you do really need to change those, are you planning on requiring a root password, or just the user's own password, or something else entirely? If the user's own password, what defines which users are allowed to make the changes?

Comment: @thepaul Yes, I need to edit files under /usr/share, and yes, I am aware that those will be overwritten when unity-2d is updated.
As for the permissions and password, that's what PolicyKit is for. I simply need to give my application access to those files.

Comment: right, I got that you are thinking of using PolicyKit. But polkit agents don't dictate *how* you authenticate users, so my questions about how to know which users should be allowed to make those changes still stands. I suspect that it may turn out quite a bit easier in this case to employ a simpler privilege separation mechanism.

Comment: Possibly just a setuid binary, possibly actually chowning the appropriate files to be part of a group into which you can add the right set of users.

Answer (score 1):

Well, the obvious solution is to have two processes, one normal user app with the GUI, and something that runs as root that manipulates files as root.

E.g. as an analog "commandline only" issue would writing a file as root:

`sudo echo Hello World >/root/hello.txt`

Does not work because the redirection is done by the interactive shell and it does not have root's access.

The classical solution is to use two processes:

`echo Hello World | sudo tee /root/hello.txt`

Now the /root/hello.txt file is opened by tee which runs as root (via sudo), which is allowed.